# Referencing DbContext in StartUp.cs is messing up my architecture in .NET Core app

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture, asp.net-core, onion-architecture

I am trying to come up with a project structure that will flow properly, but keep running into road blocks. Especially one where I can't figure out where DbContext for EF should go. I don't want my API referencing my Data layer. The only thing I can think of is installing EntityFramework to Domain layer and having the DbContext reside in there.

**TestProj.Data** Class Library (.NET Core)
Entity Framework is installed. Contains UnitOfWork class, Repositories folder with all repositories that make database calls. Will also contain EF Migrations. References TestProj.Domain for its Business Entities.

**TestProj.Domain** Class Library (.NET Core)
Models folder with all business entities, IUnitOfWork interface and all of the interfaces for the repositories in TestProj.Data i.e. ICustomerRepository.

**TestProj.Api** Web API Project (.NET Core)
I believe this should only be referencing TestProj.Domain, but I need to reference the TestProj.Data also in order to setup all of the services in StartUp.cs, i.e.

```
services.AddDbContext<TestProjDbContext>(options =>           options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddTransient<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
```

This is where I start getting confused.

**My questions:**
Is it alright for the Api project to reference both the Domain and Data projects? Seems like I need to in order to setup dependency injection in StartUp.cs

Is it correct that I am putting the interfaces for everything in the Domain project?

What project should the TestProjDbContext sit for EF? My initial thought was the Data project?

Where do items like DTOs/Pocos go? In the API project or the Domain project? U an assuming the API can have AutoMapper installed and since it references TestProj.Domain in can map the original business entities to the DTOs in the API.

Finally, where does business logic go? Rules in between the Data layer and the API. I am assuming the proper place is TestProj.Domain. Maybe this would fix my issue if the API only makes calls to the business logic in the domain instead of injecting IUnitOfWork into my api controllers I would inject TestProj.Domain.Services.CustomerService. Does this make sense?

Comment: Of course this will likely be closed as being too opinionated.  But here's something for you to consider.  If something is using a DbContext, there is no way to prevent it from referencing EF libraries.  What you probably want to do is have your API use generic constructs like `List<T>` or what not.  You might want to consider these architectures: http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/ or http://codingcanvas.com/hexagonal-architecture/

Comment: Also, Unit of Work is redundant if you're using DbContext, because a DbContext is already a unit of work.  And nearly everyone that creates such abstractions leaks implementation details through (like IQueryables) that make it difficult to actually swap data technologies.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch Not necessarily. Yes, EF is basically a Unit of Work, but what about separation of concerns if I ever want to swap it out with a different ORM. Additionally, what about trying to reduce the amount of duplicate code/query logic throughout the application. Plenty of reasons to implement UoW and Repository pattern w/ EF.

Comment: Yes, Necessarily.  Unless your UoW pattern is entirely seperated from the underlying technology, which I have never seen to be the case in any UoW implementation.  If you return an IQueryable from your UoW, then you have now coupled anything that calls the UoW to the underlying technology.  Even if you replace the technology with another IQueryable implementation, there are many Entity Framework extensions that are unique to EF, such as .Include() that make it impossible to simply replace it, so you have to redesign it if you want to swap tech, which invalidates your reason for using it.

Comment: You might argue that it's ok, because the repository will act as the translator, but if that's the case, and you need to rewrite the repository anyways if you change technology, then what was the point of slapping a redundant UoW on top of DbContext?  None.  The repositories might have just called DbContext directly.  There's nothing wrong with your Repositories talking directly to the DbContext, so long as those repositories don't expose IQueryable to the rest of your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion on this:

> Is it alright for the Api project to reference both the Domain and Data projects?

It's OK for me.

> Is it correct that I am putting the interfaces for everything in the Domain project?

YES

> What project should the TestProjDbContext sit for EF? My initial thought was the Data project?

I usually place BlahBlahContext class into Domain project

> Where do items like DTOs/Pocos go? In the API project or the Domain project?

I made for this different project, called Dto. and then referenced on this when needed.

> U an assuming the API can have AutoMapper installed and since it references TestProj.Domain in can map the original business entities to the DTOs in the API.

Sure

> Finally, where does business logic go? Rules in between the Data layer and the API.

I use for this different project in solution -> called Services

Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent response! So you are saying just put the DbContext in the Domain project so both the Api and Data projects can reference from there. I was getting stuck when configuring the ef sqlserver service in StartUp.cs because you need to pass it a DbContext. I did not want to reference my data project from the Api to do this. Even though you are saying this is ok, I prefer Api only knowing about Services project. Is this alright too?

Comment: > I did not want to reference my data project from the Api to do this.  -> and how do you plan to work with Data project classes in Api?  You need to reference it because you need this for an Automapper.     "I prefer Api only knowing about Services project." -> that's good.(I mean I don't like to place business logic into Api, using Services much better)

Comment: I plan to work with Data Project classes in the Api through the Services only (only the services will talk to Data project functions).. For example even basic classes with no business logic like GetCustomerById and GetCustomers would be called from CustomerService, this way I am only injecting ICustomerService into my controller. Is it normal to inject both Services and Repositories into Api/Mvc controllers? I am assuming the Services will also make calls to the Repositories. I think this is where most of my confusion is.

Comment: Now that I think about it should it work more like the following: Inject both ICustomerRepository and ICustomerService into the CustomersController. CustomerService never talks to Data, only accepts params. So I would do _customerRepository.GetCustomers then pass those customers into a _customerService function to do further business logic. Does this make sense at all? If it does, what if additionally the CustomerService itself talked to the Data layer is this fine. Sorry about all of these questions but I am so close to understanding this.

Comment: Any architecture is OK if it meets your needs. In my projects I add Services and Repositories into Api controller (just for small requests into Repositories as GetCustomerById) -> if you need to make all Api works only with Services -> it's OK and actually looks like 'right thing'  :)